# Statistica 64 - How do you make a macro find its file name?

Tags: vba, statistica

*Note: Editing this question to reach out to VBA people, since it might be the same process that Excel uses. SVB is just a specialized form of VBA.

I have a macro stored in file FileA.svb.

In this case, it's Main(), which calls other functions in the file.

I need my macro to find out the name of the file it's saved in.
The following works, but of course it will get a wrong answer if there is more than one macro open.

```
' Get the name of this macro / analysis  
    Dim strMacroName As String  
    strMacroName = Application.Macros.Item(1)  
    Debug.Print strMacroName
```

In Statistica (or Excel), is there a property that will allow the a function/macro to see the name of the file in which it is stored? For Excel, I don't want the XLS file, but rather the name of the code module containing the functions. I don't think SVB has the "Me" keyword, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure this is VB.Net? it seems more like VBA.

Comment: No, I tagged it VB and the system somehow changed it on me. Technically it is SVB (Statistica VB), but there us no tag for that.

Comment: Thank you for changing the tag.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the following only really work while you're in the VBE:

```
Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).FileName
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name
Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
```

I'm not aware of a way to figure it out, other then having it hard-coded into your macros.

See Mathieu Guindon's post: [Code Review: Managing a programmatically accessible stack trace](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135926/managing-a-programmatically-accessible-stack-trace)

It goes something like this...but with the `CallStack` Class fully implemented:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const ModuleName As String = "Module1"

Sub DoSomething(ByVal value1 As Integer, ByVal value2 As Integer, ByVal value3 As String)
    CallStack.Push ModuleName, "DoSomething", value1, value2, value3
    TestSomethingElse value1
    CallStack.Pop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox Application.ActiveMacroEx(False).Name
```

or

```
MsgBox Application.ActiveMacroEx(False).FullName
```